# How to reverse a created list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I need guidance to how to make a perfect reverse in my code of Haskell.
My code:

```
input :: Int -> [Int]
input x = check_1 x
check_1 x = check_2 (case x of
  0 -> []
  x -> check_1 (x`div`10) ++ [x`mod`10])
check_2 x = reverse x
```

My output:

```
Prelude -> input 12345
Prelude -> [5,3,1,2,4]
```

How I want:

```
Prelude -> input 12345
Prelude -> [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Please assist me in calling the check_2 function is a better way to reverse the list. Thanks

Comment: When is a reverse perfect ?

Comment: Less work might be `reverse [ read [x] :: Int  | x <- show 12345]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're reversing the list after each added item, so it ends up a jumble. You want to reverse once after you've added all the items. You can achieve that by getting rid of `check_2` and changing `input` to:

```
input x = reverse $ check x
```

However a better solution in this case would be to not reverse at all, but creating the list in the right order in the first place: If you change

```
check_1 (x`div`10) ++ [x`mod`10])
```

to

```
x `mod` 10 : check_1 (x `div` 10)
```

it will not only be more efficient because you got rid of the `++`, but the list will also be in reversed order from the start.

Comment: Can u tell me how can I send the returned list from check_1 into check_2 after all the items have been added. I tried your method and it works but it would not help me in my future checkings.

Comment: @Aman Since your `check_2` is just `reverse`, you can just call `check_2` where I call `reverse` and it will be the same thing.

Comment: my mistake sorry. I actually now understand what u were trying to tell me in your answer and it will help me very much. Thanks